# Explict equations for unirational Enriques surface with a nonzero 1-form

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-surfaces

I am hoping to write down very explicitly the equations for the following data:

an Enriques surface $X$ of type $\mathrm{Pic}^{\tau} = \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ such that its canonical $\mu_2$-cover is a singular rational surface. Then this $\mu_2$-cover defines a nonzero $1$-form on $X$.

Ideally, someone has written down charts for such a surface and an equation for this canonical $\mu_2$-cover and equations for its rational parametrization.

In "Pathologies of Modular Surfaces" Mumford gives an example of an Enriques surface of the correct type but where the $\mu_2$-cover is a K3 not a rational surface.

Comment: Almost certainly you can find this in Cossec-Dolgachev.